# API working from Postman, but getting error when posting from Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, iis, cors

I have a POST Im performing from Postman, which works perfect, but when Im posting through Angular, Im getting:

> [Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load (DOMAIN) due to access control
> checks.

After checking several answers here and at Google, I came up with changing web.config and express to enable CORS.

The NODE application is hosted on IIS, and I already added the customHeaders to the web.config:

```
<customHeaders>
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
</customHeaders>
```

The Angular code is pretty straight forward:

```
let APIURL = sessionStorage.getItem('endPoint') + "outside/login";
    let options = { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json') };
    let body: any = this.payLoad;
    this.httpClient.post(APIURL, JSON.stringify(body), options).subscribe(
      result => {
          .....
          .....
          .....
})
```

I also added

```
app.options('*', cors())
```

to Express but still get this error.

This worked perfect while I was using the IP address and port 3000 on the remote server. Everything crashed when I set the domain thru IIS and setup the URL Rewrite.

I want to put special emphasis on this: It works PERFECT on Postman, but it crashes through the app (localhost, or at the web server).

Thanks.

UPDATE: When stopping PM2 and stopping the IIS website, of course Postman does not work, but Angular retrieves the same error, so I tend to thing the problem is at an Angular level (?).

Here's the rewrite rule at IIS

```
 <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your js file where you require express. I assume you are requiring CORS. If not:

```
const cors = require('cors')
```

then

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });
```

and get rid of the customHeaders at your web.config. You are setting the headers twice.

```
<customHeaders>
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
</customHeaders>
```